# It won't return to main(). Why?

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    float variable_answer;

    printf("Hello\n");

    for (;;)
    {
      printf("Continue [Y or N]? ");
      variable_answer = toupper(getchar());
      getchar ();
      if (variable_answer == 'Y')
              return main();/*Here it is*/
      else if (variable_answer == 'N')
              return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The program compiled just fine and it runs smoothly all the way till the end, when it reache the "Yes or No" part, it just keep repeating printing "Yes or no" whether I key in Y or N.

Comment: you compare a float with a character , `variable_answer == 'Y'`

Comment: Also, 'return main();' does not do what you seem to think it does:(

Comment: @Rakesh_Kulkarni For the newline char.

Comment: This is related to floats iif the OP is running the code on a system where 89 and 78 cannot be represented as floats. The code actually works here, (with its recursion on main..)

Comment: @IlDivinCodino And? What's the problem?

Comment: You need to study functions, the `return` statement and the `break` statement.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **this code works**.

You had not-so-good practises, they are:

- Comparing a `float` with a `char`:

  `variable_answer == 'Y'`

  But it's ok (if you're not strictly and just care about the code works or not) because `variable_answer` still could store the value of character from the input.
- Call `main()` recursively.

  It make your program ill. In fact, there are compilers allow you to do that, some others do not.

  > C standard says nothing about forbidding recursive main calls

.

In case the code could be compiled and executed ok, please check that do you pass correct input character (ex: you might pass `y` instead of `Y`).

Comment: Haha, forgive me, I'm still new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `float variable_answer;` to `int variable_answer;`. It make no sense declaring `variable_answer` as a floating-point number, because it's only used to hold characters.

On my machine, your code works well: It terminates when I input a 'n' or 'N'. Perhaps `float` is relatively smaller on your implementation, and thus `(float)'N' != 'N'`. As a result, `variable_answer == 'N'` is never true.

Comment: And one more thing, does it print the yes or no part twice on your machine? Mine does. What's causing it?

Comment: Can you provide the complete input and output? "print the yes or no part twice" is somewhat ambiguous